# Charging for a DIY music player with Li-po battery with TP4056 IC

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, charging, tp4056

I am designing a PCB for a DIY DFmini Player based music player. I wanted to know if just putting the TP4056 IC would be sufficient for this application in the PCB or should I use a external TP4056 based charging module with over discharge protection. Also, I want to keep the PCB compact.

Answer (score 1):

One way or the other you want overdischarge protection. You can use a dedicated IC (DW01 for example), or, assuming your board has a CPU/microcontroller that still operates at the battery's minimum voltage you could use a voltage detection circuit using an input pin on the CPU and shut down the system that way.

Assuming you'll want some sort of battery indicator on the music player, you need to monitor battery voltage anyway.

The other option is the use a LiPo cell with built-in protection circuit.

Comment: I am not using a microcontroller so which one option should I stick with?

Comment: @fghbnhj If you don't have any built-in undervoltage protection, you need to provide it externally. Plenty of ICs on the market for the very purpose.

Comment: The DW01 is almost trivial to implement - it's a 6-pin IC and you need 4 external components (one capacitor, one resistor and two mosfets). The other option if you want it really easy is to use a single-cell LiPo cell with built-in protection circuit.